# Piecewise Continuity

Tags: calculus

Find all values of A and B for which f(x) is continuous for all read x values.

f(x)=

```
  (-4Ax+B, x<1)

  [A(x^2-4/x-2), -1< x <2] 

  (Bx+2, x>2)
```

I know how to solve this type of problem with only A, but where do I start when trying to find A and B?

Comment: Is this homework?

Answer (score 1):

We immediately have $f$ is continuous on $(-\infty,-1) \cup (-1,2) \cup (2,\infty)$ since, on these intervals, it is the composition of continuous functions.

We now need to ensure that also $$\lim_{x \rightarrow -1} f(x)=f(-1)$$ and $$\lim_{x \rightarrow 2} f(x)=f(2).$$

This means we must have $$4A+B=\lim_{x \rightarrow -1_-} -4Ax+B=\lim_{x \rightarrow -1_+} A(x^2-\tfrac{4}{x}-2)=3A$$ and $$0=\lim_{x \rightarrow 2_-} A(x^2-\tfrac{4}{x}-2)=\lim_{x \rightarrow 2_+} Bx+2=2B+2.$$

So, we solve the system of equations $$2B+2=0$$ and $$4A+B=3A.$$